# How to determine if a set is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning

I understand what is a convex set and also know the definition of convex set (all connecting lines lie inside the set) but when i am asked to determine if a following set is convex I am not able to apply the convex rule on that set .Can someone explain how you will find out which of the following are convex sets?

```
(a) Ω = {x ∈ Rn | x'x ≤ 10}
(b) Ω = {x ∈ Rn | ||x||2 ≤ 10}
(c) Ω = {x ∈ Rn | ||x||2 ≥ 10}
(d) Ω = {x ∈ Rn | a'x ≥ 10}
(e) Ω = {(x, y) ∈ Rn × Rn | ||y||2 ≤ 10 + x'y − ||x||22}
```

Image:
[Question in image format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FqJu.png)

Comment: If you know a little bit of linear functional analysis, the above are easy. Maybe you can set $n=1$ or $n=2$, then you can draw a figure explicitly.

Comment: MathJax, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** This is a partial answer, motivated more towards hints, but is also incomplete since I'm not sure how to get a good grasp on the final one.

---

$
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\setb}[2]{\left\{ #1 \, \middle| \, #2 \right\}}
\newcommand{\t}{\textsf{T}}
\newcommand{\n}[1]{\|#1\|_2}
$
It will help to visualize these in lower-dimensional space for your $n$ values.

- **For part (a):**

  - If $n=1$ then $\Omega = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid -\sqrt{10} \le x \le \sqrt{10} \}$, clearly a convex set.
  - If $n=2$, let $x := (\xi_1,\xi_2) \in \R^2$. Then
    $$
    x^\t x = x \cdot x = \xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 
    $$
    and $x \in \Omega \iff \xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 \le 10$. This should seem familiar (think of the equation of a circle).
  - In general, for $x := (\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_n) \in \R^n$,
    $$
    x \in \Omega \iff \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i^2 \le 10
    $$
- **For part (b):** Consider the result of part (a), and how it relates to a norm. You can, for instance, recall that the dot product is an inner product, and in $\R^n$,
  $$
  \| x \|_2 = \sqrt{ x \cdot x }
  $$
- **For part (c):** What you have in this part is (almost) the complement of the $\Omega$ in part (b). Visualize what the $\Omega$ in part (b) looks like (some sort of circle); would space (with a hole deleted) be convex?
- **For part (d):** Here I assume we fix some $a := (a_1,\cdots, a_n) \in \R^n$.

  - If $n=1$, then you get lines when you solve the inequality $a_1 x \le 10$.
  - If $n=2$, then you get half-planes, regardless of what $a_1,a_2$ are (unless they are both zero). (Try some values of them in [this Desmos demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/myz0c0tuus).)
  - In general you should be able to conjecture you (almost) always get half-spaces.
- **For part (e):**

  - Try the $n=1$ case; with some simplification, you have
    $$
    \Omega = \setb{ (x,y) \in \R^2 }{ y^2 \le 10 + xy  - x^2}
    $$
    This curiously is a filled-in ellipse.
  - Obviously, we can't visualize well anything in higher dimensional spaces though, so I'm a bit lost... The standard equation for an ellipse in $n$ dimensions would be (for $x := (x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in \R^n$ the points of the ellipse, and $a_i$ the semi-axes)
    $$
    \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2}{a_i} = 1
    $$
    but I'm not sure how to extract that easily out of what is given.

Comment: All but c) can be solved by a simple result that the set $\{f(x)\le C\}$ is convex if $f$ is convex. In Part e) the function $f(x,y)=\|x\|^2-x^Ty+\|y\|^2$ is convex (try Hessian or completing the square).

Comment: For Part d) the operator is greater than and not less than, it is convex if it is less than , is not it?

Comment: @GopalaKrishna For the part d) just apply the result to $f(x)=-a^Tx$. A linear function is convex.